# join() function is returning the type followed by a hex number instead of a concatenated string

Tags: perl

In essence, I want to take an array and create a single string with the elements of said array separated by a newline.

I have an array named `$zones`. Outputting the reference to `$zones` confirms it's an array.

The following code:

```
print_log(Dumper($zones));
print_log('-------');
print_log(Dumper(join("\n",$zones)));
```

results in the following output

```
  [2013-06-15 16:23:29 -0500] info [dnsadmin] $VAR1 = [
          'fake.com25',
          'fake.com2',
          'fake.com27',
          'fake.com43',
          'fake.com41',
          'fake.com40',
          'fake.com39',
          'fake.com37',
          'fake.com36',
          'fake.com35',
          'fake.com31',
          'fake.com56',
          'fake.com55',
          'fake.com54',
          'fake.com53',
          'fake.com52',
          'fake.com51',
          'fake.com50',
          'fake.com49',
          'fake.com48',
          'fake.com42',
          'fake.com38',
          'fake.com34',
          'fake.com33',
          'fake.com32',
          'fake.com30',
          'fake.com29',
          'fake.com28',
          'fake.com26',
          'fake.com24',
          'fake.com23',
          'fake.com69',
          'fake.com68',
          'fake.com67',
          'fake.com66',
          '0',
          'fake.com44',
          'fake.com45',
          'fake.com46',
          'fake.com278'
        ];

[2013-06-15 16:23:29 -0500] info [dnsadmin] -------
[2013-06-15 16:23:29 -0500] info [dnsadmin] $VAR1 = 'ARRAY(0x170cf0d8)';
```

I really don't want to loop over this array manually. Can someone explain why the `join()` function is returning the name of the type along with a hex number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How to do is explained well by user1937198, but why it works this way?

It's simple:

`$zones` is not an array. It's an array reference.

`join` works on lists. So if you do:

```
join("\n",$zones)
```

You essentially are calling `join` on a single-element list. And the element is a reference, which happens to stringify to `ARRAY(0x170cf0d8)`.

To make it work correctly you have to dereference it, and it is done by prefixing with real datatype (`@` or `%`, or in some cases `$`).

This can be written like this: `@$zones`, or (some, including me, say that it's more readable) as: `@{ $zones }`.

This is important when you're having nested structures, because while you can have plain array as a variable, when you're dealing with nested data structures, it's always references.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer since it explained why it works.  I didn't realize PERL had the idea of references, so this explanation was very valuable to me.

Answer (score 6):

what you want is `join("\n",@{$zones}))`

Answer (score 5):

`$zones` is array reference and to join array values you have to dereference it first by prefixing scalar `$zones` with `@`

```
print_log(Dumper(join("\n",@$zones)));
```

For more info there is short tutorial on references:
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#NAME